# Ember App Kit partials

Tags: ember.js, ember-app-kit

I'm trying to get partials working in my ember project which is using ember app kit as the build tool/project structure.
But no matter what I try ember app kit's resolver is unable to find my partial.

> Uncaught Error: The partial company/edit-note could not be found

My partial is within a subfolder ie:

`company/_edit-note.emblem`

I then tried loading the partial using emblems syntax in multiple ways:

```
> company/edit-note
> "company/edit-note"
> company/_edit-note
> "company/_edit-note"
```

I have also tried not nesting the partial but with the same result.

I noticed this issue on ember app kits repo https://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-app-kit/issues/244 and have also tried naming my partials with a prefix hyphen instead of an underscore but to no avail.

I have looked in Ember.TEMPLATES and no matter the naming convention I see the templates full path as it is ie company/_edit-note.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out that emblem > before a partial will use vanilla handlebars.
Using ember I needed to:

```
= partial "company/edit-note"
```

Also Ember App Kit prefixes partials with the hyphen.

Comment: So it delt with emblem. Good to know this :)

Comment: I hit this using grunt-emblem (without the ember app kit). Is it a bug in emblem, perhaps?